# Trouble with a java histogram issue

Tags: java

This is the question:

Design and implement an application that creates a histogram that allows you to
visually inspect the frequency distribution of a set of values. The program should read in
an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 1 to 100 inclusive; then produce a
chart similar to the one below that indicates how many input values fell in the range 1
to 10, 11 to 20, and so on. Print one asterisk for each value entered.

```
1 - 10 | *****
11 - 20 | **
21 - 30 | *******************
31 - 40 |
41 - 50 | ***
51 - 60 | ********
61 - 70 | **
71 - 80 | *****
81 - 90 | *******
91 - 100 | *********
```

Source Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class histogram
{


    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)
    throws IOException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        final int min = 1;
        final int max = 10;
        final int limit = 10;
        int[] a = new int[max];

        for (int b = 0; b < a.length; b++)
        {
            a[b] = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter Number between 1 and 100: \n (Or press 0 to stop)");
        int number = scan.nextInt();

        while (number >= min && number <= (limit*max) && number != 0)
        {
            a[(number-1)/limit] = a[(number - 1 ) / limit] + 1;
            System.out.print("Please enter a value:");
            number = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\n__Histogram__");
        for (int y = 0; y < a.length; y++)
        {
            System.out.print("   " + (y * limit + 1) + " - " + (y + 1) * limit + "\t");
            return;
        }


        for (int z = 0; z < a[b]; z++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println(0);
    }
}
```

In the last for statement, it says that b cannot be resolved to a variable. When I use java for help it sets b to 0 and the program doesn't run correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: `b` is no longer in context, it only has context in the first `for-loop`

Comment: is there a way to fix this? I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Since b was an array index in the earlier loop, I think you will need to put the last loop inside the loop to increment through the array indexes as you did in the beginning.

Changed b to y and moved z for loop inside y for loop.

```
for (int y = 0; y < a.length; y++)
{
    System.out.print("   " + (y * limit + 1) + " - " + (y + 1) * limit + "\t");
    for (int z = 0; z < a[y]; z++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```